# How do i make the background of my android program colored in java?

Tags: java, fonts, colors, background

Basically the above question, and also how do I change the font of the program when the System.out.println("text") prints on the screen? Also when I try to import android.os.Vibrator, eclipse cannot find the library. I want to make my program vibrate the phone.

Comment: Err, why is an Android program using `System.out`..?

Comment: @user2864740 what am a supposed to use then?

Comment: @user2864740 how do i print text to the screen in an android program?

Comment: To an appropriate control like a TextView..?

Comment: @user2864740 I don't know lol. Would programming in java and doing System.out.println("text") not print text?

Answer (score 0):

try this , use your layout and add color to it,

```
myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: What is the API for this? What layout are you referring to?